# Can i make my customised sql order by function?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am using MySQL, and I check some SQL tutorial, I see that that is a statement that called `ORDER BY`, which is usually `ORDER BY` a column, with `AESC` or `DESC`. But is this possible to `ORDER` the data by different sorting algo?

For example, I have follow value in my DB:

```
`id`,`name`,`notice_day`
```

I would like to `sort` the day with today first, and than the day that near today, and then, tomorrow....bababa, after finish sorting the day from today, and future, yesterday, and so far....Here is the example, assame today is `1/1/2012`

```
`1`, `peter`, `1/1/2012`
`2`, `tom`, `31/12/2011`
`3`, `mary`, `1/2/2012`
`4`, `steve`, `1/1/2011`
`5`, `bill`, `1/4/2012`
```

The sorting order I would like to is here:

```
`1`, `peter`, `1/1/2012`

`3`, `mary`, `1/2/2012`

`5`, `bill`, `1/4/2012`

`2`, `tom`, `31/12/2011`

`4`, `steve`, `1/1/2011`
```

Comment: order by can accept arbitrary functions, e.g. `order by somefield=1` will make all the records with `1` in somefield come out last.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so ascending if notice_day is today or in the future, descending if the notice_day is in the past? could do something like:

`select * from my_table order by if(notice_day >= date(now()), notice_day, 9999) asc, notice_day desc`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ##### ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)  DESC
```

mySQL isn't my strong point, but I believe the above should work.