# MYSQL: Return column time value based on current time?

Tags: php, mysql

OK I have a database with a table containing four columns. Each column has many records all with times of day entered with the mySQL TIME data type.

How do I go about querying the database and returning the time value nearest to the current time of day please?

I have it set up so that I have a simple webform that takes a user input of which column the user wants. I want the TIME value nearest to the current time from the chosen column returned to the user.

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4
11:00   11:40   11:25   11:35
12:05   12:25   12:35   12:25
```

etc

So if the user enters "3" into the webform and the current time is 12:10 I'd like the 12:35 value returned to them.

I have been Googling and I believe I need to use CURTIME(). I don't want an answer for how to take the user input and use it to query which column. I just need to know how to return a column's time value closest to the current time please! Thank you.

Comment: You would normalise your design

Comment: Are the records in any particular order? i.e most recent time first/last?

Comment: [SQL Query to show nearest date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time > CURTIME()
ORDER BY time ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

EDIT:

Maybe this is the way to go

```
SELECT * FROM table_name AS T
 WHERE T.time = (SELECT MIN(T2.time) FROM table_name AS T2
                  WHERE T2.time > ?)
```

The '?' is a placeholder for your reference time (by PHP).

Comment: Yesssss!! works great!! Although I had to change ORDER to ORDER BY....thank you sir!

Comment: You are most welcome! I edited the SQL (ORDER -> ORDER BY). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
SELECT column3, TIMEDIFF(column3, CURTIME()) AS difference 
FROM timetbl 
ORDER BY ABS(difference) ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

If you would need only closest times that are in the future (like when a user needs to catch a train), `difference` would need to be greater than 0, so you'd add `WHERE TIMEDIFF(column3, CURTIME()) > '00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it selects the last entry of time:

SELECT col1 FROM table_name order by col1 desc limit 1;