# mysql select closest date from today

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table

```
    date
-----------------------
1. 2017-01-02 20:59:00
2. 2017-01-04 10:00:00
3. 2017-01-04 11:00:00
4. 2017-01-09 17:20:00
```

Q1: Assuming today is `2017-01-03`, how can i select the above date to get the result of 2 and 3 ?

Q2: assume today is `2017-01-05`, get the result of 4 ?

Comment: Would it be accurate to rephrase that as "select all dates greater than the current date?"

Comment: As shown on this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date, 
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF(Field, NOW() ) )

Comment: @DanFarrell yeah, but i want it less than 2017-01-05 for Q1 (i dont want date no4 to show)

Comment: on what basis do you want the dates to show? Within the current day? Or the next 24 hours?

Comment: @YounElan i saw that solution earlier, but it seems that my condition didnt fit for using LIMIT

Comment: Ok, @sxio, I'm even more confused now.  You need to fix your question to ask exactly what you want.

Comment: Do you need to select the closest ones that are on the same day?

Comment: @RobSedgwick the closest date from today, example: today is 2017-01-03, i want to select date 2017-01-06 10:00:00, 2017-01-06 11:00:00, and 2017-01-06 13:00:00, but i didnt want date more than 2017-01-06, any solution ?

Comment: @GurV yess, closest one from today, on the same day...

Comment: @DanFarrell im sorry, im really bad at english, its diifcult to ask what i really want, but i guess, what i want is to select the same closest day from today...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select `date`
from your_table
where date(`date`) = (select min(date(`date`))
    from your_table
    where date(`date`) > date(now())
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE datecol > NOW() 
AND datecol < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1 Answer:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    closest_date_table
WHERE
    date(`date`) = (
        SELECT
            min(date(`date`))
        FROM
            closest_date_table
        WHERE
            date(`date`) > date('2017-01-03')
    );
```

Q2 Answer:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    closest_date_table
WHERE
    date(`date`) = (
        SELECT
            min(date(`date`))
        FROM
            closest_date_table
        WHERE
            date(`date`) > date('2017-01-05')
    );
```

[LIVE SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://rextester.com/LIW11780)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select top 1 * from tblDate where date >GETDATE()  order by date asc
```

Comment: this is sql server not mysql!

Comment: But there is sql tag and he is not mentioned the clear database server

Comment: It's the first word in the headline