# Query latest Wordpress post from a year ago

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to query a Wordpress post from a year ago, or the nearest post to that date.

I'd like to have a 'lookback' feature, allowing users to view what we were talking about a year previous.

I've tried looking through the codex but not found any inspiration yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a query using `WP_Query` that will find you a sub-set of posts.  Because the `date_query` function can handle any value that will be recognized by `strtotime` you can use '-1 year' for convenience.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_count' => 1,
    'date_query' => array( array( 'before' => '-1 year' ) ),    
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$lookback = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $lookback->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div>
    <h1>One year ago you posted:</h1>
    <?php $lookback->the_post(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: thanks - this didn't perfectly work for me, but led me to code that did work

`$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'podcast',
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'before' => '-1 year',
    ),
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => 1
); $lookback = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $lookback->have_posts() ) : $lookback->the_post(); `

Comment: Thanks, @KevinRobinson.  If you could chip in by up-voting my answer and marking it correct that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (untested):

```
global $wpdb;
$nearest_one_year_ago = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id
FROM $wpdb->posts
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( post_date, ".date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 year", time())." ) ) 
LIMIT 1");

$post = get_post($nearest_one_year_ago);

// ... go on
```

Explanation: Simply find a working SQL query for your complex query problem and then use $wpdb. However usually using WP_Query is better as long as it can be done with it.

More information:
[SQL Query to show nearest date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date)
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb